# Error en mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

este es el error :

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\10-1\tallerfinal\consultar1.php on
>   line 6

```
<?php
$documento=$_REQUEST["documento"];
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("boutique")or die("No se conecto a la base de datos");
$consulta=mysql_query("select documento,nombre,apellido from anadir1 where DOCUMENTO='".$documento."'");
while($consultax= mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
echo $consultax ["documento"]."<br>";
echo $consultax ["nombre"]."<br>";
echo $consultax["apellido"]."<br>";
echo $consultax ["telefono"]."<br>";
echo $consultax ["correo"]."<br>";
echo $consultax ["edad"]."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: <?php
$documento=$_REQUEST["documento"];
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("boutique")or die("No se conecto a la base de datos");
$consulta=mysql_query("select documento,nombre,apellido from anadir1 where DOCUMENTO='".$documento."'");
while($consultax= mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
echo $consultax ["documento"]."<br>";
echo $consultax ["nombre"]."<br>";
echo $consultax["apellido"]."<br>";
echo $consultax ["telefono"]."<br>";
echo $consultax ["correo"]."<br>";
echo $consultax ["edad"]."<br>";
}
?>

Comment: eso es completo

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` devuelve un array, por lo que para poder acceder a los valores deberías hacer un `foreach` y recorrer el array. También otra forma de acceder es:

```
"; echo $consultax [0] ["nombre"]."
"; echo $consultax[0]["apellido"]."
"; echo $consultax[0] ["telefono"]."
"; echo $consultax [0]["correo"]."
"; echo $consultax[0] ["edad"]";
```